# IE7, ckeditor and jQuery adapter not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-7, ckeditor

I am unable to open a ckeditor instance in IE7 with a jQuery dialog box. It works in Firefox, but in IE I get the following error in the web console:

> SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
>   config.js?t=B8DJ5M3, line 1 character 1
>   SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
>   en.js?t=B8DJ5M3, line 1 character 1
>   SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'options': object is null or undefined
>   ckeditor.js, line 49 character 943

Any ideas or is there a way that it is purely not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, I created the entire instance in jQuery, by predefining the properties and then assigned ckeditor to each element I wanted to have the editor

```
var properties = {properties in here};
$("#textAreaID").ckeditor(properties);
```

I dont think this is the solution entirely but it helped me get the editor working :)